# Can i devide files into group of 1000 files from a folder using java

Tags: java, svn

I am using tortoise Svn which is not able to commit huge data at a time so i want to split that data into some batches and then commit to svn.

can it be possible using java to create groups and commit to SVN.

Comment: Yes, you can do just that. I authorize you.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ? is the error from client side or server side ?

Comment: it's possible, but why not just commit the data using tortoise in batches/file by file yourself? Do you have so much that doing it by hand will take too long?

Comment: Svn equals http://svnkit.com/ ???

Comment: Writing code to commit code doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Comment: He does not want code to commit but code that creates directories and moves files into them. BTW: what is your issue with having scripts for commits? That is a common practice I thought (when I use the command line I usually have scripts doing it). What realy makes me wonder: we have the year 2011. Some friendly OSS developers develop something like svn, MIND: a tool used in production, and it has so many flaws its incredible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command line to commit your files.

e.g.

```
svn commit -m "my message"
```

or, list specific files you want to commit.

```
svn commit -m "my message" file1 file2 dir/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Java can help you out in this case. Whatever you can do with svn client java at the most can do the same. You can always use java to divide the file in 1000 part but that wont help solve your problem as in SVN you need a single file and not 1000 parts.

Comment: Hi Santosh,My folder contains lakhs of file and selecting this manually for batches is time consuming as well if i skip a single file it may cause error for my other appication as these files are input to other program and all files are necessary.

Comment: and i have to do this every day, if i select all the files at a time it gives an server failure error.

Comment: Now I got your problem. Check out SVNKit (http://svnkit.com/documentation.html) this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but if you are a UNIX user this can be achieved more easily like so:
1. cd to the directory you want to split
2. run mv `ls | head -n 1` ../bla/

This would move the first (-n 1) file from the current directory to ../bla/. You can put all that in a for loop and make a new directory each iteration of the loop

Comment: Keep in mind if you split up your directory in lots of subdirectories you have to use also the svn move command (so svn nows you local files should also move similary in the repository)

Answer (score 0):

Not java, not the most efficient, and it would bump up your revisions a lot (are you sure subversion is what you should be using?), but something along the lines of

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec svn info {} \;`

The problem is that it does it one at a time. A nicer script to batch them into lines would be a better.